# How to share a bookmark folder between two google chrome profiles

Tags: google-chrome, sync, user-accounts, bookmarks

Use case: Google Chrome I have a work profile and a home profile, and both are synced with google's mothership.

The problem is, sometimes I want to bookmark something while I am using the first account, but I actually want to access it from the second too.

Ideally, I'd like to have a "shared" folder that gets synced between the two accounts, but I haven' found a way to do it.

Notice this is not the same issue as syncing one account's bookmarks on multiple computers, that works perfectly fine already.

Answer (score 0):

Try Xmarks. It's a browser-independent external sync service. Just sync both profiles with one Xmarks account and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome keeps accounts/profiles separate.  However, they are stored locally on the hard drive. For example, on Windows the bookmarks file is located at:

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data

Additional profile(s) are named [Profile 1], [Profile 2], etc.

The default profile (the one first created when Chrome is installed) is in the [Default] directory. Bookmarks are stored in the file named [Bookmarks]. Simply copy and paste that file into the profile directory and you'll have the same bookmarks.

[Multiple Profiles in Chrome all Synced with one Google Account](https://superuser.com/questions/955928/multiple-profiles-in-chrome-all-synced-with-one-google-account/1642060?noredirect=1#comment2509941_1642060)